# Merge two tables with not equal coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 tables which contain longitude/latitude columns (the coordinates of Chicago). I need to  merge these two tables but the long/lat are not equal there. 
Is it possible to do something like:

`pd.merge(left=table1, right=table2, on=some_function_which_gets_the_most_closest_coordinates)`

Or maybe there is another way to solve the problem?

Comment: You want [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof), which is an approximate join, so on nearest key.

Comment: Yes, but merge_asof requires only one key, isn't it?